# Can I use Task.Run without await and async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have made a simple example that returns the data from a database table.

```
private Task<DataSet> GetDataAsync(string connStr)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {                
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE", conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(ds);
                    }
                }
            }
            return ds;
        });            
    }
```

What would have been the difference if a had marked the method as **async** and instead of **return Task.Run** I would have used **return await Task.Run**?

Comment: You may also find this article interesting: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answers are "yes" and "yes".

You can use Task.Run without `await` and `async`. Clearly. That's how your code is currently written and it works.

If you had marked the method as `async` you would have had to use `return await Task.Run`.

Now, in this case it's of no real value because you are just instantly returning the results of the `Task.Run`. Callers to your code can decide independently of your code if they use `await` or not on the result of your method.

The only time that it make a difference is if your code were using `await` throughout the method. For example, should there be a `FillAsync` method then this code would be valid:

```
private async Task<DataSet> GetData2Async(string connStr)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE", conn))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                await da.FillAsync(ds);
            }
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Please note that `await da.FillAsync(ds);` is fictional for illustrative purposes.

In this code then you need `async` on your method to `await` the `FillAsync`.